# What causes git checkout to not work (and not switch to branch)

Tags: git, git-bash

This one is super odd. I create a fresh clone of a repository. For one of the branches (`web`) I cannot do a `checkout` - I issue the command and the directory stays in the current branch without showing any error. I can checkout `origin/web` though, but I'm just interested to know why I can't check out the attached branch.

All other branches work ok, as illustrated below. Note the first time, it stays on `master` without error.

[image]

Comment: It *does* seem as though `git checkout web` should create a branch named `web`, with `origin/web` as its upstream. Are you on a Windows or Mac system that folds case, and if so, is there perhaps a branch named Web or weB or WEB or wEb, etc? If so that would explain the problem.

Comment: On windows; there's only one branch called "web" (case sensitivity included)

Comment: Well, that's downright mysterious then.

Answer (score 1):

When you typed `git branch -a | grep web`, you told Git to list *all* the branches containing `web` in the name, both local ones and remote tracking branches.  The output was this:

```
remotes/origin/web
remotes/origin/web-admin
```

In other words, there is no local `web` branch.  As to why you didn't get a formal error message about the `web` branch not existing, I am not certain.

If you want to create a local branch which tracks the remote `web` branch then do so via:

```
git checkout origin/web
git checkout -b web
```

Comment: Thanks, yes understood - but ordinarily a `git checkout web` should just switch me onto the branch and set up the remote track. That's how it works for other branches... so I'm wondering why that would be

Comment: @user2393012 I don't know this to be the case.  AFAIK you need to do `git checkout -b` to create a branch from another branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if the branch exists on the remote then `git checkout branchname` usually creates a new branch which tracks the remote. That's why I'm surprised it didn't work for @user2393012 here

Answer (score 1):

This is surprising because there doesn't seem to be a current "web" branch.

Maybe try the following commands and see where you get:

```
git branch -D web # Delete any existing web branch
git fetch origin web # Fetch the web branch from the origin
git checkout -b web origin/web # Create a new local "web" branch that tracks the remote
```